# Intellij evaluator strange behavior about string pool

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij IDEA to learn about java string pool, but I think I faced with an strange thing.

**The Problem is:** 
When I'm running following code snippet, everything is ok and ***b is true***. At line four I put a breakpoint.

```
        String str1 = "abc";
        String str2 = "abc";
        boolean b = (str2 == str1);
        System.out.println(b); // b is true
```

At this place I check following code in the Evaluate window of Intellij but the result was strange for me, because ***b2 is false*** this time.

```
        String str3 = "abc";
        boolean b2 = (str2 == str3);
```

I expect `b2` becomes `true` because of `"abc"` string is in string pool before str3 be declared.
Can anyone explain why this happened.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you quite certain that `str2` has not been modified between the times at which `b` and `b2` were computed?

Comment: Yes. I'm sure. All of my test code was the same that I posted in this question.

Comment: Another possibility: the `"abc"` in `String str3 = "abc"` might actually be different from the  `"abc"` in `String str1 = "abc";` and `String str1 = "abc";`  For example, "Cyrillic small letter a" and "Cyrillic small letter es" look remarkably similar (if not identical) to "Latin small letter a" and "Latin small letter c", respectively.

Comment: No unfortunately, because I copied String str2 = "abc";  to evaluator and rename it to ```str3```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IntelliJ evaluator uses its own logic for evaluating expressions and does not use the string pool in the same way as the underlying JVM. You should not use it to understand how the JVM works.